# How to query specific attribute in swiftData?

Tags: swift-data

If I have a model with a long text attribute and use swiftData for persistence. Under a view, I don't want to fetch that large attribute that may cause compromise of performance.

```swift
@Model
class myData {
   var id: UUID
   // a long text attribute
   var note: String
   // ... other attributes
}
```

Is there any way to do it like original sql. so that I can get specific attribute that I want.

```
select id, name from ....
```

Comment: You can't do this, at least not currently.

Comment: @Joakim Danielson, I found an answer and posted it. Is it right?

Comment: I don’t believe so but I don’t understand why I should confirm _your_ answer? Why not test it yourself?